# How to generate mesh and calculate volume of 3d object?

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

I saw a couple of posts dicretizing the graphic and generate DelaunayMesh to get volume of 3D object. The issue I'm having is that DelaunayMesh creates a bigger solid covering the original one, resulting more volume. Please see the following.

Let's say I have this 3D solid defined as below. In spherical coordinate,

```
R[θ_, ϕ_] := Abs[Cos[θ]]^2
```

or in Cartesian system

```
pf[θ_, ϕ_] := {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}*R[θ, ϕ];
```

This object has two lobes as shown below.

```
plot = ParametricPlot3D[pf[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

where its volume from spherical integral is 0.598399,

```
NIntegrate[ρ^2 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {ρ, 0, R[θ, ϕ]}]
```

After discretizing

```
displot = DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[plot /. (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic]]
```

I get

[image]

which still has two lobes, but with DelaunayMesh the feature disappears

```
hull = DelaunayMesh[MeshCoordinates[displot]]
```

[image]

And now it has different volume of 0.784115, greater than 0.598399 from the direct integration.

```
Volume[hull]
```

So I would like to know the best way to create mesh which gives the volume as precise as possible, both from a symbolic expression R(theta,phi) or from sampled points {{1,1,1},{3,2,2},....}.

One of the object I'm dealing with looks like this. Has many lobes, no symmetry.[image]

Here are more examples of distortion when I generate DelaunayMesh from a graphic.

From Parametricplot3D,

[image]

Then DelaunayMesh gives

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe there's something I'm missing, but why can't you just keep using your `NIntegrate[ρ^2 Sin[θ], ...]` method?

Comment: If I had analytic expression for ρ, then I would do so. However I rather have discretized data points, basically a list of {ρ,θ,ϕ} coordinates. That's why I couldn't keep using NIntegrate.

Comment: How did you generate the last plot?

Comment: It is from ParametricPlot3D[pf//.sol[θ,ϕ] {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}], where sol[θ,ϕ] is a solution from numerically solving differential equations. I can draw it from manually sampled points. In this case, I think interpolation is automatically done by Mathematica. However, distortion occurs when you convert the graphic to DelaunayMesh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DiscretizeGraphics` already hands out a `MeshRegion`, so you could go along these lines:

```
meshonly = 
  With[{coords = MeshCoordinates[displot]}, 
    MeshCells[displot, 1] (* 0: points, 1: lines, 2: faces ... *) /. 
    Line[{a_, b_}] :> Line[{coords[[a]], coords[[b]]}]]

Graphics3D@meshonly
```

[image: lines from MeshRegion extracted and displayed]

This will also work for your the more exotic shape you displayed.

## Volume

The volume can be calculated by calculating the volume of each tetraeder constructed from the mesh triangle with some *fixed* (for all calculations!) fourth point. The volume is either added or subtracted from the total volume, depending on the direction of the surface normal, which is given by the vertex ordering in *Mathematica*'s output already, so you can go about this issue in the following way:

```
Total@With[{coords = MeshCoordinates[displot]}, 
   MeshCells[displot, 2] /. 
    Polygon[{a_, b_, c_}] :> 
     coords[[a]].Cross[coords[[b]], coords[[c]]]]/6
(* .585457 *)
```

The final divisor is required, since actually six volumes are calculated by the above operation.

The difference between the original result *Mathematica* provides and this one might be the effect of `DiscreteGraphics`.

It is possible to extract the actual polygons from the original plot, also, but one finds multi-vertex-polygons there (I did not check, if they are planar or convex or self-intersection-free), which require triangularization themselves, which is not all that difficult, but requires checking mentioned conditions and dealing with the situations encountered on a case-by-case-basis first, which I did not.

Nevertheless, I hope you can make some use of my answer!

Further reference: [this publication](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/chazhang/publications/icip01_ChaZhang.pdf)

Comment: You can get a huge improvement out of this by applying `Compile`. I.e. creating a compiled function, say `compiledDotCross`, which simply takes the place of `coords[[a]].Cross[coords[[b]], coords[[c]]]]` and then applying this. For me that dropped computation time by over 20 times on a class of regions I use frequently. In fact, it rivals the built-in `Volume` when you do this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `NIntegrate` won't work?

```
ρ[θ_?NumericQ,ϕ_?NumericQ] := sol[θ,ϕ]
SphericalPlot3D[ρ[θ,ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
NIntegrate[ρ[θ,ϕ]^3/3 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

Assuming that `sol[θ,ϕ]` returns the value of your function.