# Area of surface of revolution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry

I am asked to rotate the curve $y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ from $x=-1$ to $x=1$ about the x-axis and find the area of the surface. I was able to use `RevolutionPlot3D` to show the surface.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

I used calculus to find the surface area:

```
Integrate[2 π Sqrt[4 - x^2] Sqrt[1 + (-x/Sqrt[4 - x^2])^2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Which produces the answer $8\pi$.

Here is my question. Is there some cute way of finding surface area using *Mathematica*; that is, something like using the `Area` and `Volume` commands, or some other commands?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`f[x] == Sqrt[4 - x^2]` is the distance at *height* `x` from the origin (i.e., from `{0, 0}` at *height* `x`) to the surface; hence, one can construct

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[z^2 + y^2 == Sqrt[4 - x^2]^2 && -1 <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}]
```

which looks like this:

```
DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

and directly compute

```
Area[reg]
```

> $8\pi$

Numerically:

```
Area @ DiscretizeRegion @ reg / Pi
```

> 7.99449

in very good agreement.

In general this can be applied to any revolution surface, as due to its rotational symmetry it will always be given by an equation of the form `z^2 + y^2 == f[x]` (given the revolution is around the `x` axis).

**EDIT:**

To get the volume of such a barrel, consider `reg2`, different from `reg` only in that `==` is replaced with `<=`:

```
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[z^2 + y^2 <= Sqrt[4 - x^2]^2 && -1 <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}]
```

Then

```
Volume[reg2]
```

> $\frac{22 \pi }{3}$

Comment: Alternatively, using `Area[{Sqrt[4-z^2],\[Theta],z},{z,-1,1},{\[Theta],0, 2Pi}, "Cylindrical"]` evaluates much more quickly.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks for this demonstration. I will find it quite useful teaching class.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is `DiscretizeGraphics`. Turns your graphic into a surface:

```
r = DiscretizeGraphics@
     RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, 
      RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

then:

```
In[24]:= Area@r

Out[24]= 25.5411
```

It ain't perfect, but it's close:

```
In[26]:= Area@r / \[Pi]

Out[26]= 8.12997
```

I use this to compute Van der Waals volumes of molecules. Note that `Volume` only works on closed surfaces though, but there's an answer on here (can't find it right now) that provides a way to do it with the `MeshCoordinates`.

#### Update

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75847/how-to-generate-mesh-and-calculate-volume-of-3d-object) we are. That gives you the volume.

Answer (score 5):

The most direct analog, IMO, to your plot is to use the parametric form of `Area`, where you add a theta variable for the rotation:

```
In[11]:= Area[{x, Sqrt[4 - x^2] Cos[θ], Sqrt[4 - x^2] Sin[θ]},
    {x, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
Out[11]= 8 π
```

Adding a radius variable which gives the distance from the x-axis gives you the volume (this is x-centered cylindrical coordinates):

```
In[12]:= Volume[{x, r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]},
    {x, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, Sqrt[4 - x^2]}]
Out[12]= (22 π)/3
```

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this suggestion. I used this when teaching my calculus class tonight to teach getting the volume of a surface of revolution and to do a parametric plot. Absolutely what my students needed was an introduction to parametrization.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some cute way of finding surface area using Mathematica?

I think this fits the bill,

```
WolframAlpha["rotate sqrt(4-x^2) from x=-1 to x=1 about x axis surface area",
            "Result"]

(* 25.1327 *)
```

Comment: Cheeky. :P $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 2):

Parametrize surface:

```
f[u_, v_] := {u, Cos[v] Sqrt[4 - u^2], Sin[v] Sqrt[4 - u^2]};
```

Area element:

```
i = 
 FullSimplify[Norm[Cross @@ Transpose[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]]], 
  Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, Abs[x] < 1, 0 < y < 2 Pi}]
```

gives:

```
(*2*)
```

Calculate surface area:

```
Integrate[i, {u, -1, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

yields 8$\pi$

or by considering the region of interest as a subset of a sphere of radius 2 (and orienting so "x-axis" is "z-axis", the desired surface area is `sphere`-2 * `cap`, where `cap` and `sphere` are the surface areas as suggested by the names:

```
cap = Integrate[4 Sin[u], {u, 0 , ArcCos[1/2]}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
sphere = 16 Pi
region = sphere - 2 cap
```

[image]

```
fm[u_, v_] := {Cos[v] Sqrt[4 - u^2], Sin[v] Sqrt[4 - u^2], u};
Show[ParametricPlot3D[fm[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None], 
 SphericalPlot3D[2, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False], PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Background -> Black]
```

Comment: Another very helpful answer. I want to share this with our Calc III teacher this semester.

Comment: @David thank you for the positive feedback. Happy New Year:)