# Rotate curve around x axis

Tags: plotting

How can I solve next problem? I have a curve and area which I need to rotate around x axis to make a sphere. Can it be like an animation? So far I made a half of sphere, and a whole sphere, bit I don't know how to animate it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Please post code as text instead of a screenshot; it makes it a lot easier us to try it out.

Comment: If you want an animation of this you probably need to be a bit more specific regarding your expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/revolutionplot3d-but-not-revolving-about-the-z-axis, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135358/area-of-surface-of-revolution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RevolutionPlot3D: but NOT revolving about the z axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/revolutionplot3d-but-not-revolving-about-the-z-axis)

Comment: Somehow I found this few days ago, it halped. Tnak you for your concern. Tnx for solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain if this is a particularly useful approach to the problem hidden behind your question, but this should help while maintaining the form:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Sign[x] Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -2, 2}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, sorry for less informations and no code. Somehow I got this far, bit i need to turn next thing in the sphere you made for me using some animation or parameter...here's the code:      Plot[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-1, 3}}]

Answer (score 4):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[4 - x^2], {x, -3, 3}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> "X", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I actually got this far by myself, but thank you. It still helps :)